# The term 'open' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to open the simulator but it VSCode tells me :

```
open : The term 'open' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ open -a simulator
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (open:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

**Run the command start followed by the file name and press enter**
This should to the trick, in case open is not working. Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message when I tried "open", but it worked fine with "code":

code index.html

Answer (score -1):

PowerShell has a different search path than `bash` and `sh`. To open the simulator from PowerShell on macOS you need:

```bsh
/usr/bin/open -a simulator
```